# devmem: can't open '/dev/mem': Permission denied

Tags: android, linux, root, busybox

I have 2 phones (Samsung Galaxy S4 LTE I9505, Android 4.4.2 Kitkat) which I already rooted and have root access to the phones. Previously, on my rooted Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE I9505 running Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean, I am able to get portions of the device memory via dding of /dev/mem.

I'm interested in getting the Kernel Code portion of the ram to do some reverse engineering of the phone's running kernel, and I know exactly the range of address where the kernel code is located (through use of cat /proc/iomem). However, on the 2 S4 running Kitkat 4.4.2, when I'm using adb shell (with su), I am not able to see /dev/mem mounted on the phone. When I try to use 'cat /dev/mem' or 'busybox devmem 0x80208000' I get a permission denied error.

However, when I'm using ES File Explorer with Root Explorer enabled, I am able to see both mem and kmem inside /dev. Does anyone know how to deal with this issue? I need to gain access to /dev/mem with busybox's command devmem to edit the memory on the fly.

Output of 'cat /dev/mem':

```
1|root@jflte:/ # cat /dev/mem | wc                                             
tmp-mksh: cat: /dev/mem: Permission denied
    0         0         0
```

Output of 'busybox devmem':

```
root@jflte:/ # busybox devmem 0x80208000 16
devmem: can't open '/dev/mem': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on 4.4.2 (At least on Samsung S4), Selinux is set to Enforcing which causes you not able to list out the /dev/mem or even reading it.

Since you have rooted the phone, from ADB shell, go into 'su' and use the 'getenforce' command, it should return you with 'Enforcing'. You can temporary disable Selinux by using 'setenforce 0' which will change the Selinux mode to Permissive and you are able to read or list /dev/mem